# How to solve partial fractions in integrals

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

How to solve partial fractions in integrals
$$\int { \frac1{x^ 3-x^ 2} }\,\mathrm dx$$

I got the answer as $-\ln|x|+1/x+\ln|x-1|+C$

Can anyone tell whether this correct or not

Comment: Did you differentiate to see whether you get the integrand?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. A good check is to differentiate and see if you get back to the same thing (as Ethan suggested)

Comment: is it $\frac1{x^3-x^2}$ or $\frac1{x^3} -x^2$

Comment: @pranavB23 I assume the first one, since that gives the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First write it in form
$$\frac{1}{x^2(x-1)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x-1}$$
Multiplying both sides by $x^2(x-1)$, then we get
$$1=(A+C)x^2+(B-A)x-B$$
By comparing coefficients you should get that 
$$A=B=-1$$ and $$C=1$$
I hope you know about how to integrate after integration.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use that $$\frac{1}{x^3-x^2}=-{x}^{-2}-{x}^{-1}+ \left( x-1 \right) ^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The  partial fraction decomposition of this rational function has the form
$$\frac1{x^3-x^2}=\frac1{x^2(x-1)}=\frac Ax+\frac B{x^2}+\frac C{c-1}\qquad(A,B,C\in \mathbf R).$$

To obtain the values of $A, B$ and $C$, multiply both sides by the l.c.m. of the denominators:
$$1=Ax(x-1)+B(x-1)+Cx^2$$
Setting $x=0$, then $x=1$, you obtain $B=-1$ and $C=1$. To obtain $A$, consider the coefficients of the leading monomial ($x^2$ on the right):
$$0=A+C,\quad\text{whence }\;A=-1.$$